# NSPredicate with a localized value for key

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nssortdescriptor, nslocalizedstring

I have a core data entity with a property "title", that is a string for a localized table.
I need to be able to create a predicate and a sort descriptor that will allow me to compare by Localized(title) instead of just title.
Is it possible?

---

Edit:
Say i Have an Entity called "`Person`". This entity has a property "`stringForALocalizedTable`", so that for one language `NSLocalizedString(person.stringForALocalizedTable)` will result "Alex", and for another language it will result "Alexander".
I want to create a predicate like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"NSLocalizedString(stringForALocalizedTable) == %@", @"Alex"]
```

I guess it is possible with `predicateWithBlock:` method, but I cannot use it with core data.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 2):

You could always use `%K` as formatter argument for key, like this:

```
NSString *localizedKey = NSLocalizedString(@"title", nil); // localize it.
//Use this localized key as key for search
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@",localizedKey , searchString];
```

PS: I'm wondering why would you localize the table properties.

EDIT: if you want to look for localized value then you need to localize the value instead.

```
NSString *localizedSearch = NSLocalizedString(@"title", nil); // localize it.
//Use this localized search string to look for provided value
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title contains[cd] %@",localizedSearch];
```

Comment: Right, thanks!
I need my users to be able to change the app language inside the application. Say I have an Entity : "person" and a property "name".And in my tableView, some cell displays this name (cell.label.text = Localized(title). If the app is in english, i want it to display "Maria", if its in russian - Мария. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Yeah, now its clear. So you are storing same name in different language. That way, you're looking to search for localized key.

Comment: I know its kind of late, but i have just understood that your solution is not kind of what i want. Please, see my edited question. Thank you!